# How to find a random number in python

Tags: python, random, bots

I have a random number and I want to create a bot that find it automatically but I'm stuck. Can you help me pls

I have these two variables:

```
a = random.randint(0,50)
b = 50
```

I want to make the bot find a using b.
I tried this but it's too long to make:

```
if b != a:
    b = statistics.mean(0,b)
    if b > a:
        b = statistics.mean(0,b)
    elif b < a:
        min = b
        b = statistics.mean(min,50)
elif b == a:
    "GG"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
a = random.randint(0,50)
b = 50
i = b//2
while b!=a:
    if b<a:
        b+=i
    elif b>a:
        b-=i  
    if i>1:
        i//=2
print(a,b)
```